# Lambda gives unknown application error while calling ECS load balancer within the same segment (VPC)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc, aws-application-load-balancer

There is an AWS Lambda which tries to call an API of a spring boot application located in an ECS service. The ECS service has an ALB in front of it. Now, when the lambda tries to ping this ALB DNS (through which it can call the ECS API), it gives error of "Unknown Application".

```
Unknown application error occurred Runtime.Unknown
```

Isn't this strange, because both these applications are under the same VPC and hence the same segment, then there should be no connectivity issue, but here it gives the above error.

The Lambda, ECS, ALB all come under the same AWS account, same VPC.